# Ignore ID variable when training an H2O model

Tags: r, machine-learning, h2o

It would be really great if some one can tell me how to retain an ID variable as an indicator variable but not a predictor while creating (training & testing models). I am using H2o through R. Appreciate if someone can respond with their thoughts.

Comment: If this is what you mean, I'd suggest editing the title to: "Ignore ID variable when training an H2O model" because "indicator variable" has a different meaning (usually means a binary feature).

Answer (score 2):

I think the more common use of the term "indicator variable" is to refer to a binary predictor (not a unique identifier), but it sounds like you are asking if you can just keep the ID column in your data frames but not use it for prediction.

That's easy to do in H2O -- you use the `x` argument to indicate which columns should be used as predictors, so if you leave the ID column out of that, it will ignore it.  Example with iris data:

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init()

iris$ID <- 1:nrow(iris)  #add ID column
train <- as.h2o(iris)
fit <- h2o.gbm(x = 1:4, y = 5, training_frame = train)  #fit a GBM
```

You can see that ID was not used by looking at variable importance:

```
> h2o.varimp(fit)

Variable Importances: 
      variable relative_importance scaled_importance percentage
1  Petal.Width          258.856262          1.000000   0.563269
2 Petal.Length          195.480728          0.755171   0.425364
3  Sepal.Width            2.891532          0.011170   0.006292
4 Sepal.Length            2.332296          0.009010   0.005075
```

If you predict on a test set (here I'll just use the training set for demonstration purposes), then the model already knows to ignore the ID column as well.

```
> pred <- h2o.predict(fit, train)
> head(pred)
  predict    setosa   versicolor    virginica
1  setosa 0.9989301 0.0005656447 0.0005042210
2  setosa 0.9985183 0.0006462680 0.0008354416
3  setosa 0.9989298 0.0005663071 0.0005038929
4  setosa 0.9989310 0.0005660443 0.0005029535
5  setosa 0.9989315 0.0005649384 0.0005035886
6  setosa 0.9983457 0.0011517334 0.0005025218
```